# Attribute error occurs when I run my GUI code in Python. Python gives me no information as to what the error is or what is causing it

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

This is my code and when i try to run it and use it by entering numbers into the entry fields, an attribute error occurs when i try to call on the entry variable. This is the message that appears:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\HomeWork\Yr13\Extended Project\Notepad++\Python27\Programs\GUI{c} menu+check+gen+Nth.py", line 224, in OnGenButtonClick
    n= str(Prime_Generation(Prime_Gen.entryVariable5.get(),Prime_Gen.entryVariable6.get()))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1845, in **getattr**
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: entryVariable5

any help would be greatly appreciated.
i have stuck on this problem for three days and have tried getting around the problem by using different functions and names and the error still occurs

```
import Tkinter             
from Tkinter import *
import math                


def SoS(limit):

    numbers = range(3, limit+1, 2)
    half = (limit)//2
    initial = 4

    for step in xrange(3, limit+1, 2):

        for i in xrange(initial, half, step):
           numbers[i-1] = 0
        initial += 2*(step+1)

        if initial > half:
            plist = [2] + filter(None, numbers)
            return plist         

            break


def S(m):

    sieve = [True] * m

    for i in xrange(3,(int(m**0.5)+1),2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((m-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)

    plist = [2] + [i for i in xrange(3,m,2) if sieve[i]]
    return plist


def OTS(n):

    n, correction = n-n%6+6, 2-(n%6>1)
    sieve = [True] * (n/3)

    for i in xrange(1,(int(n**0.5)/3)+1):
      if sieve[i]:
        k=3*i+1|1
        sieve[      k*k/3      ::2*k] = [False] * ((n/6-k*k/6-1)/k+1)
        sieve[k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)/3::2*k] = [False] * ((n/6-k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)/6-1)/k+1)

    plist = [2,3] + [3*i+1|1 for i in xrange(1,n/3-correction) if sieve[i]]
    return plist


def is_prime(num):

    if num <= 3:
        if num <= 1:
            return False
        return True

    if not num % 2 or not num % 3:
        return False

    for i in xrange(5, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 6):   
        if not num % i or not num % (i + 2):
            return False

    return True


def is_prime_multiple(Lower,Upper):
    NumberList = dict()

    if Lower%2 == 1:
        for i in xrange(Lower, Upper,2):
            NumberList[i] = is_prime(i)
    else:
       for i in xrange(Lower-1,Upper,2):
            NumberList[i] = is_prime(i)

    NumberList[1] = False

    return [i for i in NumberList if NumberList[i] == True]


def Prime_Generation(L,U):                                                          
    Lower = int(L)
    Upper = int(U)                                                         

    if Lower == 1:
        if Upper < 92:
            print SoS(Upper)

        if Upper >= 92 and Upper < 2250:
            print S(Upper)

        if Upper >= 2250 :
            print OTS(Upper)
    else:
        print sorted(is_prime_multiple(Lower,Upper))


def factors(n):

    f = 3
    fs = []

    while n % 2 == 0:
        fs.append(2)
        n /= 2

    while f*f <= n:
        while n % f == 0:
            fs.append(f)
            n /= f
        f += 2

    if n > 1:
        fs.append(n)

    return fs 


def Prime_Checker(N):                                                          
    NStr = str(N)
    N = int(N)                                                              
    Nfs = factors(N)
    for i in Nfs:
        if i != N:
            NfsStr = str(Nfs).strip('[]')
            resultb = [NStr,' is not a prime. The prime factors of ',NStr,' are ',NfsStr]
            return resultb.join()

        else:
            return N,' is a prime. The prime factors of ',N ,' are ',N


def PrimeFinderLamda(n,limit):                                
    nums = range(3,limit,2)
    for i in range(2, int(limit**0.5)):
        nums = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, nums)
    return [2]+nums


def NthPrime(N):
    N = int(N)
    Lower = 1
    limit = N*N
    if N == 1:
        return 2
    else:
        return PrimeFinderLamda(N,limit)[N-1]




class Prime_app_tk(Tkinter.Tk):            
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent     

        self.initialize()

def Prime_Gen_Win(self):
    Prime_Gen = Toplevel()

    Prime_Gen.grid()

    Prime_Gen.labelVariable3 = StringVar()                                          
    Title_label2 = Label(Prime_Gen,textvariable=Prime_Gen.labelVariable3,
                        relief = RAISED,fg="black",bg="white"
                        ,font = "Arial")                                          

    Title_label2.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=4)
    Prime_Gen.labelVariable3.set(u"Please enter the upper and lower limits of the prime number generation")

    Prime_Gen.labelVariable4 = StringVar()                           
    SubTitle_label1 = Label(Prime_Gen,textvariable=Prime_Gen.labelVariable4,fg="black",bg="white")                        
    SubTitle_label1.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=4)
    Prime_Gen.labelVariable4.set(u"(Please enter values no greater than 10 million)")

    Prime_Gen.entryVariable5 = StringVar()                                               
    Prime_Gen.entry = Entry(Prime_Gen,textvariable=Prime_Gen.entryVariable5)
    Prime_Gen.entry.grid(column=0,row=4)
    Prime_Gen.entryVariable5.set(u"Lower.")

    Prime_Gen.entryVariable6 = StringVar()                                               
    Prime_Gen.entry = Entry(Prime_Gen,textvariable=Prime_Gen.entryVariable6)
    Prime_Gen.entry.grid(column=0,row=5)
    Prime_Gen.entryVariable6.set(u"Upper.")

    Genbutton = Button(Prime_Gen,text=u"Generate !",command=self.OnGenButtonClick   #placing and aesthetics of button
                       ,bg="yellow",relief=RAISED,padx=10,pady=10
                       ,activebackground="red",activeforeground="white")                  
    Genbutton.grid(column=0,row=6)

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(Prime_Gen)
    scrollbar.grid(column=1,row=8,sticky="ns")        

    Prime_Gen.Result_label = Text(Prime_Gen, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set 
                         ,fg="blue",bg="white",wrap=WORD
                         ,width=100,relief = SUNKEN) 

    Prime_Gen.Result_label.grid(column=0,row=8,columnspan=2)

    scrollbar.config(command=Prime_Gen.Result_label.yview)

    Prime_Gen.labelVariable = StringVar()                           
    SubTitle_label = Label(Prime_Gen,textvariable=Prime_Gen.labelVariable,fg="black",bg="white")                        
    SubTitle_label.grid(column=0,row=9,columnspan=4)
    Prime_Gen.labelVariable.set(u"To see full list please click on the results\n and use the up and down arrows to scroll through the list")



    Prime_Gen.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)        
    Prime_Gen.resizable(True,True)
    Prime_Gen.update()
    Prime_Gen.geometry(Prime_Gen.geometry())       
    Prime_Gen.entry.focus_set()
    Prime_Gen.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

def OnGenButtonClick(Prime_Gen):
    n= str(Prime_Generation(Prime_Gen.entryVariable5.get(),Prime_Gen.entryVariable6.get()))
    Prime_Gen.Result_label.insert(END,"\nPrimes Found\n")
    Prime_Gen.Result_label.insert(END,n)
    Prime_Gen.entry.focus_set()
    Prime_Gen.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

def Prime_Check_Win(self):
    Prime_Check = Toplevel()


    Prime_Check.grid()

    Prime_Check.labelVariable8 = StringVar()                                               
    Title_label3 = Label(Prime_Check,textvariable=Prime_Check.labelVariable8,
                        relief = RAISED,fg="black",bg="white"
                        ,font = "Arial")                                                

    Title_label3.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=4)
    Prime_Check.labelVariable8.set(u"Please enter a Number to be checked for primality")

    Prime_Check.labelVariable9 = StringVar()                           
    SubTitle_label3 = Label(Prime_Check,textvariable=Prime_Check.labelVariable9,fg="black",bg="white")                        
    SubTitle_label3.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=4)
    Prime_Check.labelVariable9.set(u"(Please enter values no greater than 10 million)")

    Prime_Check.entryVariable = StringVar()                                                               
    Prime_Check.entry = Entry(Prime_Check,textvariable=Prime_Check.entryVariable)
    Prime_Check.entry.grid(column=0,row=2)
    Prime_Check.entryVariable.set(u"Enter Number here.")

    Checkbutton = Button(Prime_Check,text=u"Check !",command=self.OnCheckButtonClick  
                       ,bg="blue",fg="white",relief=RAISED,padx=10,pady=10
                       ,activebackground="red",activeforeground="white")                        
    Checkbutton.grid(column=0,row=4)

    Prime_Check.labelVariable10 = StringVar()
    Result_label2 = Message(Prime_Check,textvariable=Prime_Check.labelVariable10           
                         ,anchor="w",fg="blue",bg="white"
                         ,width=500,relief = SUNKEN,padx=3,pady=3)                    
    Result_label2.grid(column=0,row=5,columnspan=2,rowspan=100)
    Prime_Check.labelVariable10.set(u"Hello")



    Prime_Check.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)        
    Prime_Check.resizable(True,False)
    Prime_Check.update()
    Prime_Check.geometry(Prime_Check.geometry())       
    Prime_Check.entry.focus_set()
    Prime_Check.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

def OnCheckButtonClick(Prime_Check):
    Prime_Check.labelVariable10.set(Prime_Checker(Prime_Check.entryVariable.get()))         #Had to call on prime gen and display results
    Prime_Check.entry.focus_set()
    Prime_Check.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

def Nth_Prime_Win(self):                      
    Nth_Prime = Toplevel()

    Nth_Prime.grid()

    Nth_Prime.labelVariable12 = StringVar()                           
    Title_label = Label(Nth_Prime,textvariable=Nth_Prime.labelVariable12,
                        relief = RAISED,fg="black",bg="white"
                        ,font = "Arial")                        

    Title_label.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=4)
    Nth_Prime.labelVariable12.set(u"Please enter the Nth prime you would like to find")

    Nth_Prime.labelVariable13 = StringVar()                           
    SubTitle_label = Label(Nth_Prime,textvariable=Nth_Prime.labelVariable13,fg="black",bg="white")                        
    SubTitle_label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=4)
    Nth_Prime.labelVariable13.set(u"(Please enter values no greater than 664579")

    Nth_Prime.entryVariable = StringVar()                            
    Nth_Prime.entry = Entry(Nth_Prime,textvariable=Nth_Prime.entryVariable)
    Nth_Prime.entry.grid(column=0,row=4)
    Nth_Prime.entryVariable.set(u"Enter Number here.")

    Genbutton = Button(Nth_Prime,text=u"Generate !",command=self.OnButtonNthClick  
                       ,bg="green",relief=RAISED,padx=10,pady=10
                       ,activebackground="red",activeforeground="white")   
    Genbutton.grid(column=0,row=5)

    Nth_Prime.labelVariable14 = StringVar()
    Result_label = Message(Nth_Prime,textvariable=Nth_Prime.labelVariable14           
                         ,anchor="w",fg="blue",bg="white"
                         ,width=1000,relief = SUNKEN,justify=LEFT,padx=3,pady=3)    

    Result_label.grid(column=0,row=6,columnspan=2,rowspan=100)
    Nth_Prime.labelVariable14.set(u"Hello")



    Nth_Prime.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)        
    Nth_Prime.resizable(False,False)                    
    Nth_Prime.update()
    Nth_Prime.geometry(Nth_Prime.geometry())       
    Nth_Prime.entry.focus_set()
    Nth_Prime.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

def OnButtonNthClick(Nth_Prime):
    Nth_Prime.labelVariable14.set(NthPrime(Nth_Prime.entryVariable.get()))         
    Nth_Prime.entry.focus_set()
    Nth_Prime.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)


def initialize(self):                      
    self.grid()

    self.labelVariable1 = StringVar()                           
    Title_label1 = Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable1,
                        relief = RAISED,fg="black",bg="white"
                        ,font = "Arial")                        

    Title_label1.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=4)
    self.labelVariable1.set(u"Welcome to the Prime Program")

    self.labelVariable2 = StringVar()                           
    SubTitle_label = Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable2,fg="black",bg="white")                        
    SubTitle_label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=4)
    self.labelVariable2.set(u"(Please select the function you would like to use)")


    PrimeGenbutton = Button(self,text=u"Find Primes between 2 limits !",command=self.Prime_Gen_Win         
                       ,bg="yellow",relief=RAISED,padx=10,pady=10
                       ,activebackground="red",activeforeground="white")                                          
    PrimeGenbutton.grid(column=0,row=3)

    PrimeCheckbutton = Button(self,text=u"Check if a number is prime !",command=self.Prime_Check_Win  
                       ,bg="blue",fg="white",relief=RAISED,padx=14,pady=10
                       ,activebackground="red",activeforeground="white")   
    PrimeCheckbutton.grid(column=0,row=4)

    NthPrimebutton = Button(self,text=u"Find the Nth prime !",command=self.Nth_Prime_Win  
                       ,bg="green",relief=RAISED,padx=35,pady=10
                       ,activebackground="red",activeforeground="white")   
    NthPrimebutton.grid(column=0,row=5)      


    self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)        
    self.resizable(False,False)
    self.update()
    self.geometry(self.geometry())       




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Prime_app_tk(None)
    app.title('Prime Program')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you been doing the past three days to debug this? Have you proven that the variables are what you think they are, and that they have the attributes you think they do, and that these attributes have the values you think they do?

Comment: This code doesn't run due to indentation errors. Please try to cut your code down to the least number of lines possible while still illustrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the explanation. I think i get where the problem lies now. I think i know what all the variables do. When I call Prime_Gen in the OnGenButtonClick does that not refer to the Prime_Gen top level widget because Prime_Gen only exists in that way within Prime_Gen_Win so when I call on it in another function it meaning is no longer the same? If so how can I then call on the entry variables that i want and display the returned values in the text box?

Comment: To try and debug this I have been running the code looking at the error that has come up and tried to address it by changing variables around and renaming variables as well as sorting out syntax errors but when i saw this error i had no clue what to do so i kept changing things in hopes of fixing the problem. This is my first experience with tkinter so my understanding of it is not great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no quick fix for your code. It attempts to be object-oriented, but is doing so incorrectly. You need to properly define your methods, and should also adhere to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions -- specifically, methods and functions should start with a lowercase, and classes should start with an uppercase. Because you don't follow PEP8, and because of the odd way you use `Prime_Gen` to mean different things at different times, your code is incredibly hard to understand.

The crux of the problem is that inside `OnGenButtonClick`, `Prime_Gen` is not what you think it is. It is an instance of `Prime_app_tk` rather than the value that you set the local variable `Prime_Gen` to in `Prime_Gen_Win`. Thus, any attributes you assigned to the original `Prime_Gen` don't exist in this other `Prime_Gen`.

The reason is that the button is defined like this:

```
Genbutton = Button(..., command=self.OnGenButtonClick, ...)
```

In this context, `self` is the instance of `Prime_app_tk`, so that becomes the parameter passed to `OnGenButtonClick`. Inside that function you call the parameter `Prime_Gen`, in spite of the universal convention to name it `self`. This causes confusion in your code, because you also have a local variable named `Prime_Gen` in the code that creates the toplevel window.